# Custom right-click taskbar icon task using Windows Forms

Tags: c#

I've seen several [post](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Jumplists.html) regarding custom 'task' being added to WPF applications but I haven't found a compatible way to do this in Windows Forms.

Note: I'm not referring to the system notification tray.

For example, if you right click Google Chrome icon in the Windows 7 Taskbar you'll see a menu like this:

[image]

I want to do the same thing in a C# Windows Forms Application.  Is it possible or does it have to be in WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came late to the party.  There is a feature called **'Jumplists'** which would helps you to add a  new taskbar feature on right clicking the application icon:  Go through the tutorial

http://www.wpftutorial.net/Jumplists.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770767.aspx